# $X_n$ converges to zero in probability

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_n = 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and zero elsewhere. I am trying to find out whether $X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

I understand I need to prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n-0|>\varepsilon)=0 \;\; \forall \varepsilon>0$.

But what is the next step to do the computation?

Comment: So you really compute the probability $\Pr\{|X_n| > \varepsilon\}$. What did you get?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Is  it satisfied with $\varepsilon > 1$?

Now, what about if $\varepsilon \leq 1$?

Next step: write out LHS for a specific $n$, then take limits.